# Вытащить последовательность цифр из строки Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки, числа

Есть String, содержащая набор слов и цифр. В этой строке есть последовательность из 4 цифр (она там будет единственная), которая каждый раз может стоять в разном месте. Мне нужно извлечь эту последовательность. Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Можешь привести несколько примеров такой последовательности в своем вопросе и добавить что должно вывести в ответе?

Comment: Примеры: 
1. "Ханс Кри́стиан А́ндерсен родился в 1805 году." Нужно извлечь из этой строки год. Вывод должен быть 1805.
2. "Смерть его настигла 4.08.1875, в следствии травмы, перенесенной им ранее." Из этой строки так же нужно извлечь год. Вывод должен быть 1875

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью регулярных выражений:

```java
String s = "1vdvwsvw1234vnsoobvq12nvos";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}").matcher(s);
matcher.find();
String s1 = matcher.group();
System.out.println(s1);
```

Вывод: `1234`.

---

С использованием динамического программирования:

```java
static String findFourNumbers(String s) {
    for (int i = 0, n = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
            if (++n == 4)
                return s.substring(i - 3, i + 1);
        } else n = 0;
    throw new Error();
}
```

---

Лучше с использованием динамического программирования. Так намного быстрее. Вообще, быстрее сделать не получится никак.

Answer (score 2):

простой пример без регулярок

```
public static String get4digitNumber(String inp) {
    if (inp == null || inp.length() < 4) return null;
    for (int i = 0; i < inp.length(); i++) {
        if ((i + 3) < inp.length()
                && Character.isDigit(inp.charAt(i))
                && Character.isDigit(inp.charAt(i + 1))
                && Character.isDigit(inp.charAt(i + 2))
                && Character.isDigit(inp.charAt(i + 3))
        ) {
            return inp.substring(i, i + 4);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

проверка

```
    System.out.println(get4digitNumber("1234sdfsdfsdf"));
    System.out.println(get4digitNumber("sdfsdfsdf1234"));
    System.out.println(get4digitNumber("kasdlaksdjla"));
    System.out.println(get4digitNumber("2348732498239"));
    System.out.println(get4digitNumber("k324ml3k24m2l34"));
    System.out.println(get4digitNumber("Ханс Кри́стиан А́ндерсен родился в 1805 году."));
    System.out.println(get4digitNumber("Смерть его настигла 4.08.1875, в следствии травмы, перенесенной им ранее."));
```

Вывод

```
1234
1234
null
2348
null
1805
1875
```